# Generic type params not inferred when argument is a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In this code I have here:

```js
type GETR<a extends string, b extends string> = [a,b]

interface Options<A extends string, B extends string> {
  bar: GETR<A,B>
}

function foo<A extends string, B extends string, C extends Options<A, B>>(r: C) {
  return r
}

const bar:GETR<"foo", "bar"> = null as any as GETR<"foo", "bar">

const x = foo({ bar })
```

There are no type errors. [See it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gogFQEoB4CGUIA9gQHYAmAzlEcAE4CWeA5gDRQBGmO+xpF1NAfFALxQA2mjqMAugCgJ1XOQBmaAMbQA8mGCUA9niIoAgi1yESZKrQYAhQ2xOdavAN4SoTNOQBcsRKj10L3CQBfKTkAVzxFDW0oOU1NfWtjDjN6KCtsI3ZTLgYAYUT2NSidfUtubgAKDyhcgEooJxdyCGBQ8jwociCpRW0yVw94ZBQAIljNEYYRxjcR3gE8UIAbJag0EjQ8EDWSIdQxuMmoadmAiV6dYCgsfhi4iocBqEDaoA)

Now if all I change is the type of GETR from `[a,b]` to `(k:a) => b` with no other changes. Then the generic type params no longer get inferred and I have a type error:

```js
type GETR<a extends string, b extends string> = (k:a) => b

interface Options<A extends string, B extends string> {
  bar: GETR<A,B>
}

function foo<A extends string, B extends string, C extends Options<A, B>>(r: C) {
  return r
}

const bar:GETR<"foo", "bar"> = null as any as GETR<"foo", "bar">

const x = foo({ bar })
```

Has a type error. [See it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gogFQEoB4CGUIA9gQHYAmAzlEcAE4CWeA5gDRQBGmO+xpF1NAfFALxQAFAGsAXGgCU-XowBQs6rnIAzNAGNoAeTDBKAezxEUAQRa5CJMlVoMAQmbaXOtXgG9ZUJmnKjYiVMZ0ttyyAL7yygCueGq6BlDKenomDhYc1vRQ9tjm7FZcDADCqezacYYmdtzcgj5QhVLunuQQwJHkeFDkYfJqBmRePvDIKABEiXqjDKOM3qO8AniRADbLUGgkaHgg6yTDqONJU1AzcyGyfYbAUFj8CUmCroNQoRJAA)

I am trying to understand why, and what the best fix is?

Comment: Not exactly sure why inference does not work here however this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=48&pln=7&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gogFQEoB4CGUIA9gQHYAmAzlEcAE4CWeA5gDRQBGmO+xpF1NAfFALxQAFAGsAXGgCU-XowBQs6rnIAzNAGNoAeTDBKAezxEUAQRa5CJMlVoMAQmbaXOtXgG9ZUJmnKjYiVMZ0ttyyAL7yygCueGq6BlDKenomDhYc1vRQ9tjm7FZc3II+UNpxhiZ23FLunuQQwJHkeFDkYfJqBmRePvDIKABEiXr9DP2M3v28AniRADazUGgkaHggiyS9qINJI1BjEyGyHYbAUFj8CUmCrt1QoRJAA seems to work

Comment: Can't really "fix" this, more of "rewrite" this, but it doesn't work, because `C` is inferred as `Options<string, string>`, which means `bar` should be of type `GETR<string, string>`. You have given it `GETR<"foo", "bar">` instead. You might think that it's okay, but remember who's calling who here. Since you are giving it a *more specific type* than what it expects, it raises an error from TypeScript. You can't safely assign a `string` to `"foo"`. Only `"foo"` is assignable to `"foo"`.

Comment: @caTS I understand that C is inferred as `Options<string, string>` but the question is "why?" when in a very similar scenario that I shared it is correctly inferred as `Options<"foo" "bar">` ... I would expect the inference to be the same in both cases, so why is it different when the type ultimately resolves to a function?

Comment: I will just say that (a: A) => B and [A, B] are not "very similar", and that completely different rules of param inference, widening, etc. are applied to a function param. Which combination in the interface vs type causes the widening param? I don't know, but it helps to see that generic function param inference is not a trivial change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because contravariance. However, I am not 100% sure, because it also might be invariance.
There is an easy fix, just get rid of `C` generic argument:

```js
type Fn<Arg extends string, Return extends string> = (k: Arg) => Return

interface Options<Arg extends string, Return extends string> {
  prop: Fn<Arg, Return>
}

function foo<
  Arg extends string,
  Return extends string,
>(r: Options<Arg, Return>) {
  return r
}

declare const prop: Fn<"foo", "bar">

const x = foo({ prop }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w23M1N)

Consider this small example:

```js
declare let stringString: Options<string, string>
declare let fooBar: Options<'foo', 'bar'>

stringString = fooBar // error
fooBar = stringString // error
```

As you might have noticed: `stringString` and `fooBar` are not assignable to each other.

The problem is in `Arg` generic type (in your example it is `a`). If you get rid of `Arg` (`a`), your example will compile:

```js
type Fn<Return extends string> = () => Return

type Options<Return extends string> = {
  prop: Fn<Return>
}

function foo<
  Return extends string,
  C extends Options<Return>
>(r: C) {
  return r
}

declare const prop: Fn<"bar">

const x = foo({ prop }) // no error
```

It compiles, because `Return` is in covariant position.

Let's try to add back `Arg` but get rid of `Return`:

```js
type Fn<Arg extends string> = (arg: Arg) => void

type Options<Arg extends string> = {
  prop: Fn<Arg>
}

function foo<
  Arg extends string,
  C extends Options<Arg>
>(r: C) {
  return r
}

declare const prop: Fn<"foo">

const x = foo({ prop }) // still error

declare let stringPrimitive: string;
declare let fooBarPrimitive: 'bar'

stringPrimitive = fooBarPrimitive // ok
fooBarPrimitive = stringPrimitive  // error

declare let stringString: Options<string>
declare let fooBar: Options<'bar'>

stringString = fooBar // error
fooBar = stringString // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBRMdN)

There is still an error. Please check assignability of `stringPrimitive` , `fooBarPrimitive`, `stringString` and `fooBar`.

In first example, `fooBarPrimitive` literal type is assignable to string and it is expected. However, in second example, `fooBar` is no more assignable to `stringString` because of `contravariance`. Function arguments are in contravariant positions.

Let's try to add `Return` generic (in your example it is `b`):

```js
type Fn<Arg extends string, Return extends string> = (arg: Arg) => Return

type Options<Arg extends string, Return extends string> = {
  prop: Fn<Arg, Return>
}

function foo<
  Arg extends string,
  Return extends string,
  C extends Options<Arg, Return>
>(r: C) {
  return r
}

declare const prop: Fn<"foo", 'bar'>

const x = foo({ prop }) // still error

declare let stringString: Options<string, string>
declare let fooBar: Options<'foo', 'bar'>

stringString = fooBar // error
fooBar = stringString // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbn42m)

Please check assignability of `stringString` and `fooBar`, they are no more assignable to each other at all. In both cases you have got an error.

From what I understood, adding `C` generic triggers `contravariant` behavior of `Arg` generic.

This is not the first time I have faced such behavior.

Consider this example, but please turn off `strictFunctionTypes` flag:

```js
type Animal = { tag: 'animal' }

type Dog = Animal & { bark: true }
type Cat = Animal & { meow: true }

declare let animal: (x: Animal) => void;
declare let dog: (x: Dog) => void;
declare let cat: (x: Cat) => void;

animal = dog; // ok without strictFunctionTypes and error with

dog = animal; // should be ok

dog = cat; // should be error
```

`dog` is assignable to `animal` but should not be.

Now, try add generic to `animal` function:

```js
type Animal = { tag: 'animal' }
type Dog = Animal & { bark: true }

// generic is here
declare let animal: <T extends Animal>(x: T) => void;
declare let dog: (x: Dog) => void;

animal = dog; // error even without strictFunctionTypes
```

Now, `dog` is not assignable to `animal` even without `strictFunctionTypes` flag. I did not find an explanation of this behavior in docs.

See corresponding article [here](https://catchts.com/safer-types#part_1)

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) if you are interested in *-variance topic.

P.S. I will be happy if somebody will confirm or critic my thoughts, I was trying my best

Comment: First I want to say, if you are still in Ukraine and taking the time to answer my questions, I don't even know what to say - but I salute you. Thanks and hope all is well :)

Second, I've never even heard of the term contravariant before, so thanks for pointing me to that informative post.

Comment: @JDIsaacks, stackoverflow helps me to unwind . You are welcome. Apart from that, your typescript questions are always interesting ))

Comment: Btw, [this](https://twitter.com/TitianCernicova/status/1571856917177442305) is what @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir said about this answer . So, now we know for sure that the problem is in `*-variance`, however, still unable to explain behavior of `C` generic